# Write ID Field Into Another Table For ListView Filtering

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, primary-key

I have gone through so many other posts on passing the primary id from one table to new activity,  I have tried several different approaches without any success.  I currently thought I was passing it but nothing is actually appearing in the next Activity.  Here is a synopsis of what I want to accomplish.

If a user creates a new league it gets a primary ID (1).  The user clicks the newly created League and now they have the option to create a Bowler.  Of course a Bowler can belong to many leagues so I want to be able to write the League Id in to the Bowler table and this way I can do a select only leagueId = 1 and display only the bowlers associated to the league.

MainActivity

```
//On Long Click On The RecyclerView Item An Alert Dialog Is Opened With The Option To Choose Edit/Delete
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(this,
                recyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, final int position) {



                int leagueId = leaguesList.get( position ).getId();
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Main2Activity.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("value1", leagueId);
                startActivity(myIntent);
                //Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BowlerActivity.class);
                //startActivity(myIntent);

            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
                showActionsDialog(position);
            }
        }));
    }
```

Main2Activity

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.league_id );
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById( R.id.toolbar );
        setSupportActionBar( toolbar );

        String savedExtra = getIntent().getStringExtra( "value1" );
    TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLeagueId);
        final String s = myText.toString();
        myText.setText(savedExtra);


    }

}
```

League Class

```
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "leagues";

        public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
        public static final String COLUMN_TIMESTAMP = "timestamp";

        private int id;
        private String name;
        private String timestamp;


        // Create table SQL query
        public static final String CREATE_TABLE =
                "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
                        + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                        + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT,"
                        + COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + " DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"
                        + ")";

        public League() {
        }

        public League(int id, String name, String timestamp) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.timestamp = timestamp;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getTimestamp() {
            return timestamp;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
            this.timestamp = timestamp;
        }
}
```

Bowler Class

```
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Bowlers";

public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID = "league_id";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
public static final String COLUMN_TIMESTAMP = "timestamp";

private int id;
private int league_id;
private String name;
private String timestamp;


// Create table SQL query
public static final String CREATE_TABLE =
        "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
                + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID + " INTEGER,"
                + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + " DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"
                + ")";

public Bowler() {
}

public Bowler(int id, int league_id, String name, String timestamp) {
    this.id = id;
    this.league_id = league_id;
    this.name = name;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public int getLeagueId() {return league_id;}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setLeagueId(int league_id) {
    this.league_id = league_id;
}

public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}
```

}

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that your issue is that you are sending an integer but trying to get a string, when you should be retrieving an integer. Thus you should be using :-

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.league_id );
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById( R.id.toolbar );
        setSupportActionBar( toolbar );

        //String savedExtra = getIntent().getStringExtra( "value1" ); <<<< COMMENTED OUT
        String savedextra = String.valueOf(getIntent().getIntExtra("value1",-1)); //<<<< ADDED
    TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLeagueId);
        final String s = myText.toString();
        myText.setText(savedExtra);
    }
}
```

i.e. `String savedextra = String.valueOf(getIntent().getIntExtra("value1",-1));` instead of `String savedExtra = getIntent().getStringExtra( "value1" );`

- Note **-1** will be the value returned if there is no such intent, which would not correspond to an **id** (1 or greater) so -1 indicates an invalid **id**.

  - Note id's should ideally be **long** as they can be up to 9223372036854775807 as opposed to 2147483647 which is the limitation of an **int**.

Comment: by swapping out the line of code that I had with what you provided, I am getting the LeagueId.  I tried to change the int to a long and all I get is 1, which means that I am passing a valid intention, but why wouldn't I be seeing the actual id number like I do with the int?

Comment: You'd have to change to using long throughout (wherever id is used), it would only be an issue though if you exceeded 2147483647 rows.

Comment: Lol HIGHLY doubt that will happen. Thanks